# Using the MongoDB PHP driver, how do you send a MongoDB $comment with an update statement?

Tags: php, mongodb

When I'm inserting or updating data, its not clear to me how to use MongoDB's $comment from from PHP.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/comment/ says "To attach comments to query expressions in other contexts, such as db.collection.update(), use the $comment query operator instead of the meta-operator."

I am looking for a specific example of how to do a MongoDB update from PHP in which a $comment string is sent with the update statement.

Comment: In the docs, it even has an example: http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.addoption.php

Comment: The link you have provided covers the case where a find query is executed. I'm specifically looking for this solution as it relates to an update statement.

Comment: As far as I know such operators are not yet supported on those commands, I believe this is the umbrella JIRA issue: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1599